# YouTube URLs yield 404 error, only in Chrome

Tags: windows, youtube, google-chrome

I have Google Chrome 6.0.447.0 (dev). Since a few days ago, YouTube basically doesn't work for me anymore. When I try to access anything but the home page, I get a YouTube-specific page saying that "we're sorry, couldn't find the requested page".

Also, when I land directly on an internal page (like when I click on a link to a video), I get a security warning from Chrome saying that "youtube.com" is trying to redirect to a server at "google.com" and that I should not proceed. Then I (obviously) tell Chrome to "proceed anyway" and it gets me the situation described above.

I searched Chrome's support area and found a similar problem with respect to the Kaspersky antivirus. I don't use it (but do use NOD32), and the problem exists in both computers I have (one with Windows Vista and one with Windows 7). Also, the problem is strictly browser-specific, since in Firefox YouTube works just fine.

What should I do?

Comment: reinstall!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly enough, the problem went away without any distinguishable action.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the browsing data of Chrome.

( Option -> Under the Hood -> Clear browsing data )

Comment: Just tried that now too, still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is related to your YouTube/Google account? Try to open Chrome in Incognito mode.

Comment: Tried that now, doesn't work either.